# Finding arithmetic mean between first min and last maximum element in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I have following problem to solve: given an array, I need to find the arithmetic mean between elements with indexes of first minimal and last maximum element (index boundaries are not inclusive).

For example, given `{1, 5, 1, 9, 2, 7, 1, 3}`, first minimal and last maximum elements are 1 and 9 respectively, their indexes are 0 and 3, so the answer would be an arithmetic mean of elements with indexes 1..2, i.e. arithmetic mean of 5 and 1, which is 3.

I know how to find the `mean` of the whole array but how to find the `mean` between the first min and last max element of the array?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RUS");
    cout << "Enter the array: ";
    int k;
    double Sum = 0;
    double min = 0;
    double max = 0;
    const int n = 7;
    double mass[8] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

    for(k = 0; k <= n; k++){
        cin >> mass[k];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 7; i++){
        if(mass[i] > max){
           max = mass[i];
        }
        else if (mass[i] < min){
            min = mass[i];
        }
    }


    int i;

    for(i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        Sum = Sum + mass[i];

    }
    cout << Sum / 8;

    return 0;
}
```

The answer should be `3`.

Comment: Where do you find the min and max of the array?

Comment: you say 'ie 1 and 9' and then show the mean of 1 and 5, that doesnt make sense. Surely for your array it should be the mean of 1 and 9, which is 5

Comment: The task is very straightforward, albeit present in slightly convoluted way: you first need to find the **indexes** of first minimal element and last maximum element, than calculate the mean between those two indexes, given they have a distance of 1 or greater.

Comment: @pm100, the question is badly presented, but see my comment.

Comment: No ! I need to find the mean of elements `between` the max and min . Not the mean of max and min .

Comment: cmon user83869 at least post code that compiles

Comment: okay `pm100` , Now it compiles

Comment: Your question indeed should be,  "How to find the indexes? "

Comment: First of all, store the indices of the minimum and maximum elements. Then, loop over the elements between those indices and add them up. Lastly, divide by the number of elements between the indices.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you want a C++ program using C++ features.  You current program is a C program that uses C++ I/O.  Let me know if you want a C program that uses C features.

A C++ program means you should use std::vector but in case the assignment requires a C style array here is a version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    int size, *array;
    std::cout << "How many elements? ";
    std::cin >> size;
    // create the array
    array = new int[size];
    if (array) {
        // fill the array from the keyboard (could also use std::generate_n)
        std::for_each(array, array+size, [index = 0](int& value) mutable {
            std::cout << "Element " << ++index << "? ";
            std::cin >> value;
        });
        // calculate the index of the max and min
        auto minmax = std::minmax_element(array, array+size);
        std::cout << "\nThe min " << *minmax.first << " is located at index " << std::distance(array, minmax.first);
        std::cout << "\nThe max " << *minmax.second << " is located at index " << std::distance(array, minmax.second);
        // calculate the average between the indexes
        double average = std::accumulate(++minmax.first, minmax.second, 0.0, [count = 0](double average, int value) mutable {
            std::cout << "\nAdding " << value << " to average";
            return average + (value - average)/++count;
        });
        // print the result
        std::cout << "\nAverage is " << average;
        // delete the array
        delete[] array;
    }
}
```

And in case I am wrong and you are allowed to use std::vector here is a version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int size;
    std::vector<int> array;
    std::cout << "How many elements? ";
    std::cin >> size;
    // fill the array from the keyboard
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(array), size, [index = 0, value = 0]() mutable {
        std::cout << "Element " << ++index << "? ";
        std::cin >> value;
        return value;
    });
    // calculate the index of the max and min
    auto minmax = std::minmax_element(array.begin(), array.end());
    std::cout << "\nThe min " << *minmax.first << " is located at index " << std::distance(array.begin(), minmax.first);
    std::cout << "\nThe max " << *minmax.second << " is located at index " << std::distance(array.begin(), minmax.second);
    // calculate the average between the indexes
    double average = std::accumulate(++minmax.first, minmax.second, 0.0, [count = 0](double average, int value) mutable {
        std::cout << "\nAdding " << value << " to average";
        return average + (value - average)/++count;
    });
    // print the result
    std::cout << "\nAverage is " << average;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find indexes.

Then loop through the array from first minimal to index of last maximum.

You can use the code below

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int array[] = { 1, 5, 2, 10, 2, 7, 1, 10};
    int min = array[0];
    int max = array[0];
    int indexOfMin = 0;
    int indexOfMax = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    float dist = 0;
    float mean = 0;
    int arrSize = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        if(array[i] >= max ){
            max = array[i];
            indexOfMax = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Max is at index [" << indexOfMax << "]  : " << max << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++){
        if(array[i] == min){
            continue;
        }
        if(array[i] < min){
            min = array[i];
            indexOfMin = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "Min is at index [" << indexOfMin << "]  : " << min << endl;

    if(indexOfMin > indexOfMax){
        indexOfMax++;
        indexOfMin--;
        for(int i = indexOfMax; i <= indexOfMin; i++){
            sum += array[i];
        }
        dist = indexOfMin - indexOfMax + 1;
    }else if(indexOfMin < indexOfMax){
        indexOfMax--;
        indexOfMin++;
        for(int i = indexOfMin; i <= indexOfMax; i++){
            sum += array[i];
        }
        dist = indexOfMax - indexOfMin + 1;
    }

    mean = sum/dist;

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << " && dist: " << dist << endl;
    cout << "Mean: " << mean << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Max is at index [7]  : 10
>
> Min is at index [0]  : 1
>
> Sum: 27 && dist: 6
>
> Mean: 4.5

---

Output for `int array[] = {1, 5, 1, 9, 2, 7, 1, 3}` :

> Max is at index [3]  : 9
>
> Min is at index [0]  : 1
>
> Sum: 6 && dist: 2
>
> Mean: 3

Comment: First minimal is 1 and last maximum is 9 . So the elements between them are 5 and 1 . The sum is 6 and arithmetic mean is 3.

Comment: Okay.  I got it.  Thanks alot.  That helped

Comment: And in your code you can write  indexofmin and indexofmax in one for loop instead of two.  Right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with some changes. Accept the answer if it is the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think in terms of iterators, not values.  Instead of recording the first minimal value, create an iterator that points the element one past it.  Instead of recording the last maximal value, create an iterator that points to that value.  You can then pass the *range* defined by these to iterators to `std::accumulate` to do the summation and then divide this by the `std::distance` of the same range to find the mean.  But be aware that the number of elements between the min and max might be 0.